# Getting linear representation of sound level

Tags: java, android, audio

I am trying to get a linear representation of the sound level of audio data captured through AudioRecord, but the only code I can find on the net returns Exponential values. can anyone point me in the right direction?

the code i have found so far is

```
private double soundPressureLevel(final float[] buffer) {
    double value = Math.pow(localEnergy(buffer), 0.5);
    value = value / buffer.length;
    return linearToDecibel(value);
}

private double linearToDecibel(final double value) {
    return 20.0 * Math.log10(value);
}

private double localEnergy(final float[] buffer) {
    double power = 0.0D;
    for (float element : buffer) {
        power += element * element;
    }
    return power;
}
```

Comment: What is the code that you've seen?

Comment: Do you know that sound typically is measured in decibels which is an logarithmic scale?

Comment: i have added the code i have been using to my answer. I did know this yes, but I am hoping to find a linear result. the reason im looking for this is that i am using the sound level to alter the height of a bar as an visualization to let the user know sound is being detected. because of the exponential values, the bar is being scaled very quickly at lower levels and stays at a higher level  showing very little movement

Comment: Ok, do you think that maybe the "linearToDecibel" is the bit of code you won't want if you require a linear response?

Comment: P.S. If you are visualising sound level, you will almost certainly want to stick with a logarithmic scale.

Comment: well...you would think. though I tried it and the results went very quickly from 0 to around 250 and stayed around there

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  If you skip the `linearToDecibel` call, the result should be proportional to the signal level (assuming `localEnergy` works as expected).  Do you have a test input that demonstrates otherwise?

Comment: I was using a musical instrument (saxophone). anything above very very quiet playing was jumping to around 200 - 250 (without the linearToDecibel()) regardless of whether i was playing very loudly or at a medium volume

Comment: i have added my localEnergy method to the question

Comment: Yes, that's to be expected.  Your ear's interpretation of "quiet", "medium" and "loud" will actually follow a log scale.  In terms of energy, "medium" is much much more energetic than "quiet".  That's why we typically use a log scale for visualising sound levels.

Comment: ok. I'm going to go and do more reading on the subject as i clearly dont understand it well enough. thanks